# I'm trying to create a Mermaid diagram in Github (inside MD file) that has code blocks inside it

Tags: github, codeblocks, mermaid

I'm fairly new to Mermaid and I'm using it inside of Github in an MD document. I'd like to be able to do text indentation inside of a node. e.g.

```
flowchart TD
   A["heading point:
         list item 1
         list item 2
     "]
```

The renderer will ignore any leading spaces on each line though.

Note that the github renderer seems to be not as feature rich as the Mermaid live editor. For example I don't seem to be able to do MD inside a Mermaid code block using the nested quotes and backticks.

Many thanks

Comment: As a workaround, adding `&nbsp;` or `&emsp;` might help?